# unable to extract white color text in tesseract

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, opencv3.0, python-tesseract

I am developing an app to extract text from Images using **OpenCV and Tesseract**. I stuck in a place *when Images contain text in White color* and in case of Images having mix of White and some other color.

I am easily able to extract text if it is not white color, but it dosen't work in case of Text is White. I am using Tesseract for extracting data from text.
Below is my code for image processing before passing to tesseract:

```
image = cv2.imread(imgPath)
filename = getFileName()

img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#cv2.imwrite('python_scripts/temp/img2gray_' + filename, img2gray)

""" below removing shadow from image """
rgb_planes = cv2.split(img2gray)

result_planes = []
result_norm_planes = []
for plane in rgb_planes:
    dilated_img = cv2.dilate(plane, np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8))
    bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(dilated_img, 21)
    diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(plane, bg_img)
    norm_img = diff_img
    norm_img = cv2.normalize(diff_img, norm_img, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
    result_planes.append(diff_img)
    result_norm_planes.append(norm_img)

result = cv2.merge(result_planes)
result_norm = cv2.merge(result_norm_planes)
img2gray = result


origImage = image.copy()

_, new_img = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # for black text , cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV

# to manipulate the orientation of dilution , large x means horizonatally dilating  more, large y means vertically dilating more
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (13, 13))
dilated = cv2.dilate(new_img, kernel, iterations=9)  # dilate , more the iteration more the dilation
cv2.imwrite('python_scripts/temp/dilated_' + filename, dilated)

_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)  # get contours

(imgH, imgW) = img2gray.shape[:2]
#logger.info("imgH: " + str(imgH) + ", imgW: " + str(imgW))
ctr = 0


contoursSort = {}

for contour in contours:
    # to sort contours from top to bottom
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    contoursSort[y] = contour

orderedContours = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(contoursSort.items()))

for key, contour in orderedContours.items():
    # get rectangle bounding contour
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    # Don't plot small false positives that aren't text
    if w < 35 and h < 35:
        continue

    length = x + w
    breadth = y + h
    area = length * breadth
    cv2.rectangle(origImage, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 0), 2)
    # don't consider contour which is touching the border
    if x != 0 and y != 0 and x != imgW and y != imgH:
        #logger.info("x: " + str(x) + ", y: " + str(y) + ", length: " + str(length)
        #   + ", breadth: " + str(breadth) + ", area: " + str(area))

        croppedImg = origImage[y:(y + h), x:(x + w)]
        croppedGray = cv2.cvtColor(croppedImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        ctr = ctr + 1

        th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(croppedGray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,75,10)
        #th3_height, th3_width = th3.shape[:2]
        #th3 = cv2.resize(th3,(2*th3_width, 2*th3_height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        th3 = cv2.GaussianBlur(th3,(5,5),0)

        tessImgPath = 'python_scripts/temp/th3_' + str(ctr) + "_" + filename
        cv2.imwrite(tessImgPath, th3)

        tessText = runTesseract(tessImgPath)
        os.remove(tessImgPath)
        logger.info("tess text: " + str(tessText))
```

> Please guide me how can i process image through OpenCV so that both
>   white and other color text can be extracted in single shot.

One way which i am trying now is to get the portion of white color in image, if it is less than other colors then do `bitwise_xor` of image and then pass it to Tesseract.

[image: sample image]
[image: sample image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also facing the issue. It does not recognize grey or light grey texts at all.

Comment: @YogeshSanchihar you can get grey and light grey text by doing `adaptiveThreshold` or `threshold`. If unable to do so, please share any sample image in any free dropbox. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on text-extraction where tesseract failed to extract text with multiple colors.

It is not issue with white color. I tried extraction on your images. Tesseract gives the exact output for second image as the text contains only single color.

But the result for first image is not so good as half of the text is in black and another is in white with gray outline. so try this to get full white and black image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("XDJFq.jpg")

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# do adaptive threshold on gray image
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 250, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 11)

# write results to disk
cv2.imwrite("Full_white.jpg", thresh)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: The result is here]

So, It makes the gray outline of white text to black, after this extract text from it.
The final result is

```
Coming together is a

BEGINNING...

. ‘keeping together is

PROGRESS...

working together is

SUCCESS...
```